# How to customize a horizontal listview with left/right button on uwp?

Tags: uwp, uwp-xaml

I want to write a horizontal listview with left/right button like Netflix uwp version. When mouse hover on it, left/right button show. Otherwise, hide.
And when click on it, the listview move items left/right.

[image]

Comment: use **Flipview** control [link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/design/controls-and-patterns/flipview) you can bind the listview inside the FlipView

Comment: have you tried **Flipview** ?

Comment: Hi, sorry for late reply. Currently my project use horizontal ListView, and this app will run on xbox. So, I will find another way to customize ListView instead.

Comment: Please create custom ListView with UserControl and add left and right `VerticalNext`  `VerticalPrevious` button then bind with listview scroll method.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found an awsome control writen by Pieter Nijs. See
[Custom UWP Control: Step-Through ListView](https://blog.pieeatingninjas.be/2016/01/17/custom-uwp-control-step-through-listview/)